# Ant Jar task corrupts manifest encoding

Tags: encoding, ant, jar, character-encoding, manifest.mf

Per [Jar specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) manifest encoding has to be UTF-8.
In some scenario (eg merge), manifests produced by ant's jar task got corrupted and special chars would be double encoded.

Original manifest (utf-8):

```
...
Application-Name: spécial
...
```

Final manifest (utf-8) after beeing processed by ant's jar task:

```
...
Application-Name: spÃ©cial
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jar tasks beeing able to process file-sets allows the developper to specify the original manifest character encoding.

Unfortunately, although the mandatory (final) encoding is utf-8 there is no default in ant's jar task and then the original manifest processing is relying on the platform default... `Windows-1252` in my case where the original manifest (coming from another jar) is truly in `utf-8`

Solution : specify the encoding in the task attribute

```
    <jar destfile="final.jar" filesetmanifest="merge" manifestencoding="UTF-8">
        <zipfileset src="original.jar">
    [...]
        </zipfileset>
    </jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found my old [bugreport](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238263) about this for NetBeans.

> As a workaround, I added manifestEncoding="${source.encoding}"
>   attribute to the copylibs tag in build-impl.xml